# Add two project types in one VS extension

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, vsix

I've added new project type using [this guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc512961%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Everything is Ok, I could create such projects. But when I am trying to add another one project type - I couldn't see it in new project types, there is only the first one. I've tried to use the first project type Fabric, to create different Fabric for each project type - nothing helped. How could I add second project?

Comment: This sounds like an ID, name collision or path collision. Why shouldn't you be able to add more then one project type if they are completely different? You should check the excellent guide you linked for how [Basic Project Types are created](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc826178(v=vs.110).aspx). Somewhere you've colliding metadata. Obviously, you can't add twice the same project type.

Comment: What does one VS Extension mean.

Are you trying to create two project types from two different Visual studio project and add them to the same extension ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally found the error.
Problem is that I'vent read manual carefully and skipped this Note:
"The  element must match the LanguageVsTemplate argument of the ProvideProjectFactory attribute in the SimpleProjectPackage.cs file."